# Set circle fill color using Quartz

Tags: objective-c, ipad, quartz-graphics

I want to add fill color to a circle. This code dont work:

```
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0, 0, 225, 1);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0, 255, 0, 1);
    CGContextAddArc(context, pointWhereUserClickedX, pointWhereUserClickedY, 50, 0, 2*3.14159265359, YES);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
```

What is wrong?

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you did not fill the circle with the fill color.

```
 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect { 
     //your code and add this line:
     CGContextFillEllipseInRect(contextRef, rect);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Must use in the last line this:

CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);

Comment: If doesn't work please check that drawRect is called by using setNeedsDisplay. In my solution I have a UIView and the above code is in drawRect. If you want a more detailed answer add more code, please.